# RichTextBlock scroll to specified offset

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, richtextblock

I have a `RichTextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer`. The content of the `RichTextBlock` is very long. How can I scroll to the specifed Offset (the offset of `RichTextBlock`) in code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` does not have a Setter Property for `VerticalOffset` - However it provides with a Public Method to achieve your requirement.

```
_ScrollViewer.SetVerticalOffset(40.0);
```

Cheers!